# How to detect whether Vim has been invoked by another shell command?

Tags: autocmd, invocation, startup, quit

I would like to modify the behavior of one of my mapping but only when Vim is reading data which were piped to it by `$ vipe`.

The mapping closes/quits the current window/session depending on certain conditions. When Vim is reading data which were piped to it, I would like the mapping to execute `:cquit`, so that it reports an error to the shell and the output of the shell command is not displayed in the terminal when I quit (or the rest of the pipeline is not processed).

`$ vipe` is a shell utility, included in the `moreutils` package, whose man page contains this:

```
NAME
       vipe - edit pipe

SYNOPSIS
       command1 | vipe | command2

DESCRIPTION
       vipe allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped
       between programs. Your editor will have the full data being piped from command1 loaded into it, and when you
       save, that data will be piped into command2.

ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
       EDITOR
           Editor to use.

       VISUAL
           Also supported to determine what editor to use.
```

As an example, one could use it to count the number of files/directories in the current working directory with `$ ls` and `$ wc -l`, using Vim in the middle to interactively remove some entries:

```
$ ls | vipe | wc -l
```

But, I don't know how to detect that Vim has been invoked by `$ vipe`.

I tried to use the `StdinReadPre` and `StdinReadPost` event like this:

```
augroup standard_input
    autocmd!
    autocmd StdinReadPre * nno cd :echo 'hello'<cr>
    autocmd StdinReadPost * nno cd :echo 'hello'<cr>
augroup END
```

But it didn't work, when hitting `cd`, `hello` was not displayed.

The reason why it didn't worked is probably because Vim wasn't invoked with the `-` argument, because this works:

```
$ ls | vim -
```

And `:h StdinReadPre` and `:h StdinReadPost` seems to confirm this:

```
                            *StdinReadPost*
StdinReadPost           After reading from the stdin into the buffer,
                before executing the modelines.  Only used
                when the "-" argument was used when Vim was
                started |--|.
                            *StdinReadPre*
StdinReadPre            Before reading from stdin into the buffer.
                Only used when the "-" argument was used when
                Vim was started |--|.
```

I also tried to check the contents of the internal variables `v:progname` and `v:progpath` but they both report `vim`, not `vipe`.

Is there a way to detect whether Vim has been invoked by another shell command (`vipe`, `git commit`, ...)?

Comment: `vipe` and `git` open Vim with a temporary file, so stdin isn't involved.

Comment: For your particular problem, maybe `alias vipe='vipe --suffix vipe'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `vipe`, `git commit` (and many other programs which invoke an editor) use the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` variables (unless you specify an editor for `git` with `git config core.editor`), you can use that variable to invoke Vim in such a way that you can detect it:

```
export EDITOR='env called=1 vim'
```

Then, in Vim, `$called` will have a value of 1, which you can use to detect whether it was called by a command.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how reliable it is but I found how to get the PID of the parent of a process [here](https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line):

```
ps -o ppid= -p <pid of the process>
```

And how to get the name of a process from its PID [here](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name):

```
ps -p 1337 -o comm=
```

One can get the pid of the Vim's process with the `getpid()` function, so combining the previous 2 commands, maybe this expression could get the name of the parent of Vim:

```
expand('`ps -p $(ps -o ppid= -p '.getpid().') -o comm=`')
```

I've tried to use it in my mapping like this:

```
if expand('`ps -p $(ps -o ppid= -p '.getpid().') -o comm=`') ==# 'vipe'
    cquit
else
    ...
endif
```

It seems to work.

Comment: I do something similar to determine whether `vim` has been invoked from `gdb`, but using the /proc file system and Vim's internal commands. `let ppid = split(readfile("/proc/".getpid()."/stat")[0])[3]` `let pcmd = split(readfile("/proc/".ppid."/cmdline", "b")[0])[0]` `if fnamemodify(pcmd, ":t") =~ "gdb$"` `...`

Comment: @garyjohn I've just tested it in my mapping, and it works too. I didn't know about the `/proc` folder and how we could use it to get the pid of processes. This is great, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @garyjohn at least on Linux, you can eliminate the `getpid()` by reading `/proc/self/stat` directly

Comment: @muru: Thank you. That does make it cleaner and hopefully a _little_ faster.

Comment: @garyjohn `let ppid = readfile("/proc/".getpid()."/ppid")[0]` may also work